# How to use .values_counts() for list items in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` which looks like this:

```
data = [['Alex','Japan'],['Joe','Japan, India']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Countries'])

Name Countries
Alex Japan
Joe  Japan, India
```

So I want to **modify** `df` in such a way that when I implememt `df['Countries'].value_coun
ts()`, I get

```
Japan 2
India 1
```

So I thought that I should convert those strings in `df['Countries']` into a list using this:

```
df['Countries']= df['Countries'].str[0:].str.split(',').tolist()

    Name    Countries
0   Alex    [Japan]
1   Bob [Japan, India]
```

But now when I run `df['Countries'].value_counts()`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

All I wish is that when I run a `.values_counts()` I get 2 for Japan and 1 for India. Please see if you can help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series`, so possible use `value_counts`:

```
s = df['Countries'].str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
print (s)
Japan    2
India    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using [`series.str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df.Countries.str.get_dummies(',').sum()
```

---

```
India     1
Japan     2
```